Find special character in Excel
In Microsoft Excel, how can I find cells containing a specific special character? For instance and in particular TABs (0x09).
In Word, I can type ^t to mean TAB and a few other special characters can be specified this way. I can also copy a TAB character (say in Notepad) and paste that into the Word 'Find' textbox to then search with it. But Excel has no such ^ sequences AFAICS and pasting strips TAB characters (or replaces each by a space)...
One workaround I found works per column: copy a column, paste it into (say) Notepad, there search for a TAB and work your way back from there. But this is very cumbersome, especially with many columns (and/or TABs). An alternative is to save the sheet as CSV and search in it with Notepad: also quite a hassle.
Is there a trick to do it inside Excel?
Of course I could set up a formula like =LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1;CHAR(9);"")) to count TABs per cell... :-(
Similarly for CRs.

If you are comfortable using the VBA Immediate window, then something like ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(Chr(9)).Select would find the first cell in the sheet that contains a horizontal tab. FWIW, similar questions have been asked before: https://superuser.com/q/1676422/348859 and https://superuser.com/q/1005170/348859 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/75540953/4475014

Depending on your scope, you could use conditional formatting - for example,

to find TAB, add conditional formatting with "Classic"
select the range of cells and with top-left cell being the active cell
enter `=ISNUMBER(FIND(CHAR(9), relative reference to cell))
for example, with E6:E19 selected, with E6 being the active cell, enter =ISNUMBER(FIND(CHAR(9),E6))



Great creative idea!
